# How is this supposed to be the secret ending?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

This video:

is titled "second Secret ending".

I got this ending in the game (you just travel to Valhalla after finishing the main quest). But I was told that you have to collect the 160 fragments to watch the secret ending. And I definitely haven't done that. So how come I got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the secret ending: it's similar (enough to trip me up as well), with the same camera work, but the dialogue is different. You can see the secret ending here:

<sup>(If the time code jump doesn't work, it starts at 6:25)</sup>

Rather than waxing poetical, Caius instead:

> describes his master plan to rebuild the world without Etro.